# Why is it that we can redirect the input of 'less' command, but we can't run less without any arguments?

Tags: shell, unix, less-unix

as far as i learned in programming, when i want to add the input redirection to my program, i write my program as when it executed, it waits for the user's input (with *std::cin* or something similar). but i got confused by less command.

We all know that we can do something like this:

```
ls -la | less
```

but when we try to execute

```
less
```

without any arguments we get an error. how come ?!

Comment: for the sake of completeness, I asked more detailed about this on _Unix & Linux_:

[How isatty function works in brief.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118156/how-can-we-distinguish-that-input-to-our-program-is-directed-or-it-is-just-a-use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `less` accepts input from stdin or from a file.

Since it doesn't make sense to accept input from a terminal (just to display the same input back to a terminal), the `less` program probably checks if stdin is a terminal (with `isatty`) and refuses to run.

See [`man 3 isatty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)

Comment: That was the answer i was looking for :D thank you Dietrich Epp

Comment: btw can you give me more documents on `isatty` ? some kind of a tutorial, that how can i pass the a pointer or something of my input stream to this function?

Comment: @Shnd: Just pass 0 for stdin.

Answer (score 2):

Less is a pager, a UNIX term for a program that shows output one screenful at a time. If you pipe a program's output to less, it shows the output one page a time. If you pass file names on the command line, it shows those files page by page.

If you do neither, there's nothing to page through. It throws an error because there's nothing sensible it can do. What do you want it to show?

Comment: can you guide me to implement this in my programs. i mean how can i get the redirected input without waiting for user's input (like std::cin) ?

Comment: That doesn't explain how `less` distinguishes between (a) being executed with no arguments with stdin redirected from a pipe or file, and (b) being executed with no arguments with stdin coming from the keyboard.