# How can we distinguish that input to our program is directed or it is just a user's input by using isatty function?

Tags: shell, input

I've asked a similar question on Stack Overflow on this link:

[Why is it that we can redirect the input of 'less' command, but we can't run less without any arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185509/why-is-it-that-we-can-redirect-the-input-of-less-command-but-we-cant-run-les)

which leads me to this:
How can we distinguish that input to our program is directed or it is just a user's input ?!
**can someone give me a small example on how can i use `isatty` function ?**

Comment: You should add to your question the reason why you're asking about `isatty()`, just for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of `isatty`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  if( isatty(STDIN_FILENO) )
    puts("Connected to a terminal");
  else
    puts("Not connected to a terminal");

  return 0;
}
```

In use:

```
$ gcc isatty.c 
$ ./a.out 
Connected to a terminal
$ echo hello | ./a.out 
Not connected to a terminal
```

Doesn't get much simpler than that!

Comment: Wow, that was simple :D it will solve my problem, thanks. btw what do we mean by saying _"Connected to a terminal"_ or _"Not connected to a terminal"_ exactly ?! I mean, when do we say that a program is connected to a terminal and when it is not !

Comment: @Shnd Strictly speaking it is never connected to a terminal unless we are using a particularly old piece of hardware. A real terminal was separate from the computer, back in the days when mainframes were common. Nowadays they are just implemented in software, this is what `tty` devices are all about. See this Q (second most upvoted Q here!) for more info - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

Comment: I learned a lot today. Thank you @Graeme for your precious time.